# How to get a name based on a id in the same row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I am new to mySQl and am trying to learn it. I want to get the name of Johns chef. So John Chefnr is 100. I want to make a query where I get chefname Frank as output. How do I do this? Help is appreciated!

```
+-----+-------+--------+
| eNr | name  | chefNr |
+-----+-------+--------+
| 120 | John  | 100    |
+-----+-------+--------+
| 100 | Frank | 200    |
+-----+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Add what code that you have tried. It is a simple query that you can find by a simple google search.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select chefnr from tablename where name = 'John'
```

will return `100` in the column `chefnr`.
You can use it like this:

```
select name from tablename
where enr = (select chefnr from tablename where name = 'John')
```

to get the name of John's chef.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fJMDfcVd5CcSW6eAc2YtAq/0).
Result:

```
| name  |
| ----- |
| Frank |
```

Comment: How do i get the name based on the chefNr. So that you dont use the where clause for John but know that chefNr 100 is Frank, because that is his aNr.

Comment: If I understand what you want: `select name from tablename
where chefnr = (select enr from tablename where name = 'Frank');`

Comment: If you know chefNr = 100 then it's simpler: `select name from tablename where enr =100`

Comment: Lets say I have hundred records. I want to retrieve the name of the chef based on his chefNr not on a specific name. chefNr is the same as a aNr but for people who have a higher rank.

Comment: If you have more questions I suggest to post them as new questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need a join that involve the same table two time  ..

```
select  a.name as chefname 
from  my_table a 
inner join  my_table b on a.eNr = b.cheNr 
where  b.name is  'John'
```

or using chefNr

```
select  a.name as chefname 
from  my_table a 
inner join  my_table b on a.eNr = b.cheNr 
where  b.chefNr = 100
```

Comment: How do i get the name based on the chefNr. So that you dont use the where clause for John but know that chefNr 100 is Frank, because that is his aNr.

Comment: Lets say I have hundred records. I want to retrieve the name of the chef based on his chefNr not on a specific name. chefNr is the same as a aNr but for people who have a higher rank.

Comment: SO is not  a free coding service  .. but an question/asnwer  site .. based on your 
 question there are answer  that solve your question  ..   .. extend  the request .. each time someone post  and answer  is not fair

Comment: It seems that you misunderstood my question. I tried to specify it each time. I asked the same question every time. jdm